# Automatically recreate a routers remote routees when the remote JVM/process restarts

Tags: akka

I have a router which deploys it's routees on a remote system. When that remote JVM process restarts, how can I have the router recreate the routee instances on the remote system?

Tried using 'resizer' in the router config, but it doesn't seem to work.

In general, what's the recommended approach for recreating remote actors when a remote JVM restarts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cluster aware routers handle this. You should perhaps not use a router. Instead use ordinary actor and you have full control of the behaviour. In 2.3.0-RC1 the routing logic can be used in ordinary actors, and you can add and remove routees.